# How to automatically use typewriter font in arrays?

Tags: fonts, arrays, typewriter

I'm trying to write a script on formal logic. The source code looks something like this:

```
some text...

\[
\begin{array}[]{c | c}
p   &   (\lnot p) \\ \hline
1   &   0 \\
0   &   1 \\
\end{array}
\]

some more text...
```

How can I make it, that the text inside the array is written in typewriter font? I tried something like this, which works fine:

```
\[
\begin{array}[]{c | c}
\texttt{p}   &   \texttt{($\lnot$ p)} \\ \hline
\texttt{1}   &   \texttt{0} \\
\texttt{0}   &   \texttt{1} \\
\end{array}
\]
```

The problem is, that it is much work and not dynamic. So if I would like to change it back to a normal font, I would need to remove everything myself. Is there an elegant solution to this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want a typewriter font? This is perfectly ugly.

Comment: You might want tabular numbers instead, which you can get in `fontspec`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\ttfamily}c} 

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ T | T }
p  & ($\lnot$p) \\ 
\hline
1  & 0 \\
0  & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Since `\ttfamily` is a text-mode command, I suggest employing a `tabular` environment rather than an `array` environment.

Comment: Thank you @Mico!

Answer (score 6):

I think you might have an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

With many OpenType fonts, you would be able to use the command

```
\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}
```

to get fixed-width numbers in a more-attractive font.  You might wrap this in an environment, such as:

```
\newenvironment{arraymono}%
  {\begingroup\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}\begin{array}}%
  {\end{array}\endgroup}
```

You might also find the Unicode figure space, which is exactly as wide as a tabular digit, useful here:

```
\newcommand\figspace{^^^^2007}
```